# Polynomial time "fairness" algorithm that assigns leaders for $m$ tasks amongst $n$ workers.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, algorithms, network-flow

Suppose we have $n$ workers and $m$ tasks. Suppose each task has a workforce $S_i \subseteq \{1, 2, .., n\}$. Note that $S_i \cap S_j \neq \emptyset$ is possible (and expected).

Given this configuration, we want to assign a leader $s_i$ for each task $i$  such that $s_i \in S_i$.

Moreover, we want a fairness criterion for each person:

If a person is in taskforces $S_{i_1}, ..., S_{i_k}$ with sizes $n_1, ..., n_k$ respectively, then the person should be given at *most* $\frac{1}{n_1} + \frac{1}{n_2} + ... + \frac{1}{n_k}$ tasks to lead or as this may not be an integer, the person should be given at *most* $\lceil\frac{1}{n_1} + \frac{1}{n_2} + ... + \frac{1}{n_k}\rceil$ many tasks to lead

Is there a polynomial time algorithm that, given taskforces $S_1, ..., S_m$ assigns leaders in a fair way (where "fairness" is determined as above)?

I think we have to write this as a max flow problem and use algorithms such as Edmonds & Karp, Dinics, etc. Not sure though.

Comment: The only condition for leaders that you have mentioned is that they have to be a member of the task force they lead . . . . What are the other conditions for the leader? You have the sum of reciprocals there, but what do they represent? "The person [leader?] should be given at most . . . " what? At most that many people to lead? At most that many tasks?

Comment: At most that many projects to lead

Comment: I've edited it.

Comment: OK, I see the edits. But there may be a problem. If a member of 2 tasks with forces of 5 and 8, your formula says they should be given at most $\lceil 0.325 \rceil,\,=1$ task to lead. But if they are added to 2 more tasks with forces of 2 and 4, then according to your 'fairness' algorithm, they should be required to lead no more than $\lceil 1.075 \rceil = 2$ tasks--an increase. Is this intended? Should workers who are assigned more tasks also be expected to lead more tasks? Or should it be the other way around?

Comment: Yes, that seems to be correct. I think the idea is that each $S_i$ chooses it's leader randomly. But yeah I agree that it seems a bit strange that workers with more tasks get asked to lead more tasks.

Comment: I was thinking of setting a bipartite matching thingy from $n$ workers to $m$ tasks. Except put another predecessor layer of another $n$ nodes and there is a $1$ to $1$ correspondence with each of these two layers of $n$ nodes with edge capacity being given by the fairness algorithm above. Then I could use some max flow algorithm.

Comment: Your approach will work, you also need to set a capacity of 1 for the $m$ tasks (you only want 1 worker on each task). The you can do max flow. A solution will always exist, this is easily checked using the maxflow-mincut theorem.